# Very slow update with nHibernate with a SQLite database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using nHibernate with one session per method. I'm using Castle Dynamic Proxy to open a session and a transaction before executing the method and I commit the transaction and close the session right after the execution of this method.

I'm using a SQLite database and if set cascade to SaveUpdate or None doesn't change anything. nHIbernate is configured with Fluent nHibernate with the default configuration.

When I flush the session, it takes more than 2 seconds.

```
public void AddNewChild(LightPatientDto patient, LightPatientDto child)
{
    var ePatient = this.Session.Load<Patient>(patient.Id);
    var eChild = this.Session.Load<Patient>(child.Id);

    switch (ePatient.Gender)
    {
        case Gender.Male:
            eChild.Father = ePatient;
            break;
        case Gender.Female:
            eChild.Mother = ePatient;
            break;
        default:
            Assert.FailOnEnumeration(eChild.Gender);
            break;
    }

    this.Session.Update(eChild);
    this.Session.Flush(); // <== takes more than 2 seconds
}
```

NHibernate profiler gives me this SQL is executed in 2008 ms. When I copy paste this SQL using a SQLite administration tool, it's executed in 90 ms.

```
UPDATE Patient
SET    BirthDate = '1964-05-06T00:00:00.00' /* @p0 */,
       Fee = 0 /* @p1 */,
       Height = 0 /* @p2 */,
       InscriptionDate = '2007-05-21T00:00:00.00' /* @p3 */,
       PlaceOfBirth = 'xxxxxx' /* @p4 */,
       PrivateMail = '' /* @p5 */,
       PrivateMobile = NULL /* @p6 */,
       PrivatePhone = '0496/xx.xx.xx' /* @p7 */,
       Reason = 'diabète' /* @p8 */,
       Father_id = 2 /* @p9 */,
       Insurance_id = 1 /* @p10 */,
       Mother_id = NULL /* @p11 */,
       Practice_id = 1 /* @p12 */,
       Profession_id = NULL /* @p13 */,
       Reputation_id = 1 /* @p14 */
WHERE  Person_id = 3 /* @p15 */
```

How can I optimise the execution time?

**EDIT 1**

As @csanchez suggested, I've succeeded to add Dynamic Update for my entity. Now when I'm looking the SQL into NH Profiler, I've got this:

```
UPDATE Patient
SET    Father_id = 2 /* @p0 */
WHERE  Person_id = 21 /* @p1 */
```

Which is a lot optimised! But, the execution time is ... 1852 ms o_O

In the debugger, I see that it is committing the transaction that takes time... And I have no clue why it is so slow...

**EDIT 2**

Each patient has medical pictures that are stored into a table as bytes arrays. Here's the SQL for the table creation (done by Fluent nHibernate)

```
CREATE TABLE Picture (
  Id               integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  Bitmap           blob,
  Creation         datetime,
  LastUpdate       datetime,
  Notes            text,
  IsImported       bool,
  Tag_id           bigint,
  Patient_id       bigint,
  ThumbnailBitmap  blob,
  /* Foreign keys */
  FOREIGN KEY (Patient_id)
    REFERENCES Patient(), 
  FOREIGN KEY (Tag_id)
    REFERENCES "Tag"()
);
```

If I drop the data with `DELETE Picture` and restart the application, the update is light speed fast.

It seems like nHibernate try to be smart and does something that slows down everything. But event if I execute a pure SQL query with this code, the update still takes more than one second:

```
using (var tx = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
{   
    var sql = "UPDATE Patient SET Father_id = 2 WHERE Person_id = 21";     
    var query = this.Session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
    query.ExecuteUpdate();

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you update is the Parent or the Mother you could use `dynamic-update="true"`, in the mapping file of the Patient.

Answer (score 0):

Is this performance hit just with the first commit to the DB. SQLite may have some spin-up time.

You say "session per method" yet it looks like you're using a module-level session variable. The more that is done with a Session instance, the slower it will become due to caching. If this is going to be more of a batch operation, consider the StatelessSession.

Also check the logging configuration for NHibernate + Log4Net. The more detailed the logging, the slower NH will respond.

Comment: nHibernate logging just logs from WARNING to FATAL. As I said, a dynamic proxy opens a session, calls the method and eventually closes the session. Every time I call the method, this simple update takes 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should not flush your session every time you make a change to data. You should let NHibernate buffer updates and flush bulk changes. Otherwise, they would have made flush implicit operation and not have you worry about it.

Comment: If I remove Flush(), then committing the transaction takes 2 seconds